# How to save Name and Number from editText and fetch those data?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

I don't know how to save the data from these `editText`(as shown below in the image) and save those data on external storage, and then fetch those data from the saved file to the respective `editText` boxes, the buttons which I have implemented are for Picking the contact details like name and number from `phonebook`, which is working properly and there are two more buttons I have included for save and load operation.

Screenshot

[image]

Comment: **Welcome to Stack Overflow**, StackOverflow is neither a forum, tutorial site nor web search replacement. We can [**help with certain problems**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), but it's your job to [**put some efforts**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) in the first place, including elementary [**(re)search**](https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=KlC2WdDPCKzT8gfFz72QDw). Read [**how to ask perfect question**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)

Comment: I suggest you start with Google. A quick search will give you several hits that explain how to store data in a database or a file.

Comment: https://www.journaldev.com/9400/android-external-storage-read-write-save-file.. Take a look if you wish to save the data in file. But I suggest to save the data in database if it is large.

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong all your controls are there, in `ListView` or `Recyclerview`. 
Make sure you set tag to each of your `EditText` properly since based on these tags you can fetch all details from the respected `EditText` present on each rows. 
Here is the how you can set tag to controls

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {           
  rowView.setTag(yourdata_object);
  return rowView;
}
```

You can get tag details as mentioned below

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long 
id) {

  YourDataObject item = (YourDataObject ) view.getTag();
  Intent i = new Intent(GetRota.this, someOtherActivity.class);
  i.putsomedata;
  startActivity(i);
}
```